# How to convert Vec<u8> to u32 in Substrate runtime?

Tags: rust, string, parse

AFAIK, we can't use std in Substrate WASM runtime, what is the most effective way to convert a string to a number in runtime.

For example: string "48" in Vec to 48 in u32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you don't have access to `std`, you do have access to `core`, and that should have all the tools you need.

For example, this should work fine inside of the runtime environment:

```
fn string_to_number(text: Vec<u8>) -> Result<u32, DispatchError> {
    let text_as_string = core::str::from_utf8(&text).map_err(|_| "not a string")?;
    let number: u32 = text_as_string.parse().map_err(|_| "not a number")?;
    Ok(number)
}

#[test]
fn string_to_number_works() {
    let text = "48".as_bytes().to_vec();
    assert_eq!(crate::string_to_number(text).unwrap(), 48);
}
```

I am not sure why you would do this though, as parsing text into a number is absolutely not something the runtime is meant to do, and will lead to a bunch of wasted computation and potential user errors.

You should instead do any kind of text parsing in the front-end and only send expected types over to your runtime.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn Tabrizi for the answer. The reason I did that in runtime is because value stored in the storage of the other pallet is set as Vec<u8>, to use them in different pallet so I would need to convert to u32 to handle the specific logic.

Comment: For more specific example, one of on-chain attribute of NFT that stored on chain with the format like `BTreeMap<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>` that stored "ArtistFee":"100" (it's a dynamic attribute so no hard-coded properties), I just need to convert "100" to u32 to handle some calculation.

Comment: If you know any more efficient way or design, really appreciate it if you can share because I am new to Substrate but found it's really awesome framework to work with.

Comment: Rather than store the bytes as a string, you should store it as the underlying type, like a `Compact<u32>`, and then deserialize it as such.