# How to convert usize to u32 in ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, convert

How can I convert a usize to u32?

For example I want to store the length of a Vector (usize) to a variable u32
I tried
i32::from(v) // or v.into().   where v is the length of the vector but errored

I tried v as u32 and it compiles fine but I am interested in finding the correct way of doing this as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273169/how-do-i-convert-between-numeric-types-safely-and-idiomatically
suggests that generally speaking using as instead of from should be avoided

However trying to use from in ink! errors I am guessing because of no std access

Also looking at similar posts like [How to convert Vec<u8> to u32 in Substrate runtime?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-to-convert-vecu8-to-u32-in-substrate-runtime)
I can see that core::str::from_utf8 was used for a different conversion

So my questions are:

Q1: how to convert usize to u32

Q2: where to read more about conversions between types in ink!
e.g. read about examples similar to core:: above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, using binary `as` operator to convert from one type to another is common way. In case of `usize`, if `usize` value is greater than max value of u32, then it will cause panic at runtime. To handle this safely, Rust also offers traits that facilitate type conversions upon implementation like [this in the under `convert` model of rust std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html).

[practice reference](https://github.com/123oli/rustlings-rust/tree/main/exercises/conversions)

Comment: Many thanks. This has been very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out that:

`as` won't cause a panic. It just loses some precision. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1cf0b2dc9955ef9d6a54c7c95998f331

---

You should never not do this, and you need to write some logic to handle this. Something like:

```rs
if usize_v as u128 > u32_v as u128 { ... } else { ... }
```

But if your logic doesn't care about the precision losses. Or you know the `usize` value is always smaller than the `u32::MAX`. Just use `as`.

Comment: I really appreciate the valuable comments and add-ons